# Batch script error "The syntax of the command is incorrect"

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file that is throwing a syntax error at a particular line.

```
@ECHO ON
CD %~dp0
SET XDA_HOME_DIR=%CD:~0,-4%
SET "JAVAHOME=%JAVA_HOME%"
SET XDA_CONFIG_PROPERTIES=%XDA_HOME_DIR%\config\xda-config.properties
IF "%JAVAHOME%"== ""( 
ECHO JAVA_HOME not set
GOTO END)
```

Note: This is not the full script. I have posted just a part of it.

Below is the error thrown:
[image]

What is causing the syntax error message?

Answer (score 2):

error comes from here:

```
IF "%JAVAHOME%"== ""( 
ECHO JAVA_HOME not set
GOTO END)
```

you need a space before the opening bracket:

```
IF "%JAVAHOME%" == "" ( 
  ECHO JAVA_HOME not set
  GOTO END
)
```

Comment: thanks , it worked , however i see another error,  "C:\Softwares\xCP\XDA_win64\xDA\bin>IF "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10;" == ""
 (
ECHO JAVA_HOME not set
 GOTO END
)
set was unexpected at this time.

Comment: Please edit code and error messages into the question. It is difficult in comments.

Comment: there are was ";" in the path , when i removed it worked , thanks for the help